# JSch SFTP file upload/download - why use the methods that return a stream?

Tags: inputstream, sftp, outputstream, jsch

The `ChannelSftp` class has versions of `get()` and `put()` methods not returning anything, or returning `InputStream`/`OutputStream`.

What's the use case for using the methods returning streams, and reading/writing the files byte by byte, versus using the easy `get()` and `put()` methods where you specify the source and destination paths, and let the program do everything for you?

My guess is if you are downloading and playing a video/audio file would be one case, but what if you just move files to/from one server to another?  Any point in using the streams then?

Here is the documentation:
http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any other I/O interface, the variants with streams are useful when you do not manipulate files, but in-memory data.

For example, you might have produced the content based on user input and you want to upload it. You do not need the local copy in a file. So you stream the in-memory data to SFTP.

Streams are also useful abstraction.

---

If you are uploading from a file or downloading to a file, use the overloads that take paths. Creating a file stream is unnecessary overhead in this case.